# Why aren't array access and pointer arithmetic equivalent with full optimization?

Tags: c++, assembly, c++20, pointer-arithmetic, arrayaccess

Why doesn't this code produce the same assembly? (g++ -O3)
I know little of assembly but it seems case 2 accessing has less instructions, so should be preferred, right? I am asking this because I wanted to implement a wrapper class with an access operator that returns a pointer `int* p = a[i]` (so access is `a[i][j]`, instead of `a[i*3+j]`), but don't know if it's worth it. Thank you for any help.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    int a[9];
    int i, j, k;

    // Case 1
    std::cin >> i >> j >> k;
    *(a + i*3 + j) = k;

    std::cin >> i >> j >> k;
    (&a[i*3])[j] = k;

    std::cin >> i >> j >> k;
    *((&a[i*3])+j) = k;

    // Case 2
    std::cin >> i >> j >> k;
    a[i*3 + j] = k;

    std::cout << a[0];

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/13arxcPqz

Edit: For completeness, this change where `a` is moved to the right is exactly as in case 2, as the operator+ now associates left.

```
// Case 2 again
std::cin >> i >> j >> k;
        *(i*3 + j + a) = k;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x89453aK4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions `*(a + i*3 + j)` and `a[i*3 + j]` are not equivalent at the level of C++.  Since binary `+` associates left-to-right, the former is equivalent to `*((a + i*3) + j)` while the latter is equivalent to `*(a + (i*3 + j))`.  They can produce different results if, for instance, the sum in `i*3 + j` would overflow `int`.

For a concrete example, consider a 64-bit machine with 32-bit `int` like your x86-64 system, and suppose we had `i == 600'000'000` and `j == 2'000'000'000`.  Suppose, instead of your array of length 9, that `a` points into an extremely big array on a 64-bit.  The first expression adds `1'800'000'000` and then `2'000'000'000` to `a`, yielding `a+3'800'000'000`.  The second adds `1'800'000'000+2'000'000'000` first, which overflows and causes undefined behavior.  On some compilers, the behavior might be to "wrap around", yielding `a+(-494'967'296)`, a completely different address that is 16 GB away from the other one.

The generated assembly reflects this distinction.  In the second case, the addition `i*3 + j` is done as plain 32-bit addition, which would wrap around on overflow.  Since `j` is in memory, once we get `i` in a register, we can use a plain `add r32, m32` instruction to do the addition.  But in the first case, `i*3 + j` must be done as a 64-bit addition to yield correct pointer arithmetic.  So `j` must be sign-extended to 64 bits before adding, and this cannot be done in a single memory-source add instruction.  Instead, we first use `movsx r64, m32` to load `j` into a register with sign extension, then `add r64, r64` to do the 64-bit addition.  This explains why it takes an extra instruction.

Which of the two "should be preferred" is less about the efficiency and more about whether your code could conceivably be called with arguments that would overflow, and what you want to have happen in that situation.  Worry about correct behavior before optimizing.

---

Just to highlight the code I'm talking about: `*(a + i*3 + j) = k;` is performed at lines 12-13 and 16-20 in [the asm code linked in the question](https://godbolt.org/z/13arxcPqz):

```
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+4]        ; eax = i, zero-extend
        movsx   rdx, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]        ; rdx = (int64_t)j, sign-extend to 64 bits
        ;;; lea     rsi, [rsp+4]              ; unrelated, set up args for next cin
        ;;; mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt3cin ; unrelated, set up args for next cin
        lea     eax, [rax+rax*2]              ; eax = i*3, still 32 bits
        cdqe                                  ; rax = (int64_t)i*3, sign-extended
        add     rax, rdx                      ; rax = (int64_t)(i*3) + (int64_t)j
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]       ; edx = k
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16+rax*4], edx ; perform the store
```

Then the code for the next two versions, `(&a[i*3])[j] = k;` (28-29 and 30-36) and `*((&a[i*3])+j) = k;` (44-45 and 48-52) is the same; these also correspond to two "pointer plus index" steps and never do the `int` addition.

Whereas `a[i*3 + j] = k;` is at lines 60-65:

```
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+4]        ; eax = i
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]       ; edx = k
        lea     eax, [rax+rax*2]              ; eax *= 3
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]        ; eax += j (32 bit add!)
        cdqe                                  ; rax = (int64_t)(i*3+j)
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16+rax*4], edx ; do the store
```

Comment: Assembly output is same. Please check the link to godbolt in the question. I listed that in my answer

Comment: @ArminMontigny: I don't think so.  I added annotated code to my answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Note that signed `int` overflow is UB, so compilers are allowed to assume it doesn't happen.  They do need to handle negative numbers correctly, though, so yes, `a[i*3 + j]` only has to sign-extend `i*3 + j` so it has the option of doing it once after.  But `a + i*3 + j` has to sign-extend `3*i` separately from `j`.  The more efficient way isn't an option.  They could both compile to the less-efficient asm if the compiler wanted: UB allows that.  But since it's less efficient they choose not to.

Comment: @Peter `a[i*3 + j]` is undefined behavior if `i*3 + j` is negative.

Comment: @prl: Oh right, because `a` is an array object, not just a pointer which might be pointing into the middle of an array.  So the `cdqe` is a missed optimization; `i*3 + j` is already zero-extended into RAX, and the only time when sign-extending wouldn't be equivalent is the UB case.  Neat, that might be a good optimization for GCC to actually look for, to optimize away useless sign-extensions in cases like this where people use signed `int` math to generate an array index, for cases where it can be proven that a negative value would be UB.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the assemblyoutput carefully. Sorted by colors.

The output is the same.

For the last case the assembly for the IO operation is different.

But basically all the same.

Even, if C++ language and rules require different implementation, the optimzing compiler will produce the optimized same code.

```
// 1.
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+4]
        movsx   rdx, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        lea     eax, [rax+rax*2]
        cdqe
        add     rax, rdx
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16+rax*4], edx
// 2.
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+4]
        movsx   rdx, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        lea     eax, [rax+rax*2]
        cdqe
        add     rax, rdx
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16+rax*4], edx
// 3.
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+4]
        movsx   rdx, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        lea     eax, [rax+rax*2]
        cdqe
        add     rax, rdx
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16+rax*4], edx
```

Comment: I missed it too at first, but the one that's different is actually the fourth occurrence in the linked code; lines 60-65 in the asm output.  Note for instance that the `movsx` isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers, I was exactly referring to that ```movsx``` which seemed like something extra for me (I don't know much assembly).